# Почему java требует сделать поле константой, тогда как оно уже является константой?

Tags: java, компиляция, преобразование-типов, константа

Значение аннотации `@EnableRedisHttpSession` инициализируется значением константы `SESSION_TIME_TO_LIVE`:

```
@Configuration
@EnableRedisHttpSession(maxInactiveIntervalInSeconds = SessionConfig.SESSION_TIME_TO_LIVE)
public class SessionConfig extends AbstractHttpSessionApplicationInitializer {

    public static final Integer SESSION_TIME_TO_LIVE = 600;

    ...
}
```

При попытке запуска приложения возникает ошибка: `java: element value must be a constant expression`. Так как поле `SESSION_TIME_TO_LIVE` имеет иммутабельный тип `Integer`, а само оно отмечено `final`, то его вполне можно считать константой. Так почему возникает ошибка?

Любопытно, что ошибка исчезает, если заменить `Integer` на `int`. Интересно, что также проблем не возникает с использованием `String`, хотя это не примитив:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(AdminReportController.REST_URL)
@AllArgsConstructor
public class AdminReportController {

    protected static final String REST_URL = "/reports";

    ...
```

Почему такое происходит?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Integer* - это класс-обертка примитивного типа *int*, и не может быть константным выражением, т.к. создание экземпляра класса происходит во время выполнения программы, а константное выражение должно быть вычислено компилятором ещё до запуска программы.

По поводу класса *String* могу сказать, что, как и в большинстве других языков, этот класс стоит особняком по одной простой причине: основная часть констант в любой программе - это строковые литералы. Было-бы расточительством копировать их в динамическую память при запуске программы ради одного лишь объектно-ориентированного подхода.
Объекты строковых литералов в Java являются фактически ссылками на область памяти в DATA-сегменте и компилятор **может** работать с ними, как с примитивными данными.

Comment: Это хороший ответ, однако есть ещё один момент, поэтому я отредактирую вопрос и хотел бы, чтобы вы его тоже пояснили. Дело в том, что со String проблем не возникает. Понятно, у него нет примитива, но тем не менее это объект. Почему так?